# webscraping using rvest package comes out empty

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping, rvest

There is a table of taxes by country at the link below that I would like to scrape into a dataframe with Country and Tax columns.

I've tried using the rvest package as follows to get my Country column but the list I generate is empty and I don't understand why.

I would appreciate any pointers on resolving this problem.

```
library(rvest)
d1 <- read_html(
  "http://taxsummaries.pwc.com/ID/Corporate-income-tax-(CIT)-rates"
  )
TaxCountry <- d1 %>%
  html_nodes('.countryNameQC') %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: how many columns you expect in output? There are 4 _columns_ in source

Comment: Two, see my post.

Comment: Apologies. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is dynamically loaded and the DOM altered when javascript runs in the browser. This doesn't happen with `rvest`.

The following selectors, in the browser, would have isolated your nodes:

```
.twoCountryWrapper .countryNameAndYearQC:nth-child(1) .countryNameQC
.twoCountryWrapper .countryNameAndYearQC:nth-child(1) .countryYear 
.twoCountryWrapper .countryNameAndYearQC:nth-child(2) .countryNameQC
.twoCountryWrapper .countryNameAndYearQC:nth-child(2) .countryYear
```

But, those classes are not even present in `rvest` return.

The data of interest is actually stored in several nodes; all of which have ids within a common prefix of `dspQCLinks`. The data inside looks like as follows:

[image]

So, you can gather all those nodes using css attribute = value with starts with operator (^) syntax:

```
html_nodes(page, "[id^=dspQCLinks]")
```

Then extract the text and combine into one string

```
paste(html_text(html_nodes(page, "[id^=dspQCLinks]")), collapse = '')
```

Now each row in your *table* is delimited by `!,` , so we can split on that to generate the rows:

```
info = strsplit(paste(html_text(html_nodes(page, "[id^=dspQCLinks]")), collapse = ''),"!,")[[1]]
```

An example row would then look like:

```
"Albania@/uk/taxsummaries/wwts.nsf/ID/Albania-Corporate-Taxes-on-corporate-income@15"
```

If we split each row on the `@`, the data we want is at indices 1 and 3:

```
arr = strsplit(i, '@')[[1]]
country <- arr[1]
tax <- arr[3]
```

Thanks to @Brian's feedback I have removed the loop I had to build the dataframe and replaced with, to quote @Brian, 
`str_split_fixed(info, "@", 3)` [which] gives you a character matrix, which can be directly coerced to a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(info, "@", 3))
```

You then remove the empty rows at the bottom of the df.

```
 df <- df[df$Country != "",]
```

---

**Sample of df:**

[image]

---

**R**

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html('http://taxsummaries.pwc.com/ID/Corporate-income-tax-(CIT)-rates')
info =  strsplit(paste(html_text(html_nodes(page, "[id^=dspQCLinks]")), collapse = ''),"!,")[[1]]
df <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(info, "@", 3))
colnames(df) <- c("Country","Link","Tax")
df <- subset(df, select = c("Country","Tax"))
df <- df[df$Country != "",] 
View(df)
```

---

**Python:**

I did this first in python as was quicker for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://taxsummaries.pwc.com/ID/Corporate-income-tax-(CIT)-rates')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
text = ''

for i in soup.select('[id^=dspQCLinks]'):
    text+= i.text

rows = text.split('!,')
countries = []
tax_info = []

for row in rows:
    if row:
        items = row.split('@')
        countries.append(items[0])
        tax_info.append(items[2])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(countries,tax_info)))
print(df)
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [str_split_fixed](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/str_split_fixed)

Comment: I would welcome suggestions on improving the above with a form of _apply_ .

Comment: You don't need `apply` or a loop. Given the vector of strings, `str_split_fixed(info, "@", 3)` gives you a character matrix, which can be directly coerced to a dataframe and any undesirable rows filtered out.

Comment: thanks @Brian. I have updated my answer along the lines of what I think you meant. I note the I'm left with two "empty" rows at the bottom so have used apply to remove those, but the answer looks so much cleaner, and I suspect is more efficient. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @QHarr and Brian: Thank you for the detailed explanations!

Comment: @QHarr, you don't need `apply` there either. `df[df$Country != "",]` is the vectorized form.

Comment: Many thanks @Brian. So I can simply say df <- f[df$Country != "",] Nice!  You have been really helpful.